# Antialiased pixels from Swift code is converted to unwanted black pixels by OpenCV

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, image-processing, antialiasing

i am trying to make some pixels transparent using swift code by setting anti-aliasing true and remove path pixels to transparent. For further process i had sent UIimage to  opencv using c++  that convert edge of path to black pixels.
i want to remove that unwanted black pixels. How can i remove those blacks pixels generated by opencv?

in opencv just converting image to mat and from mat to UIImage, the same problem occurs.

swift code:

```
guard let imageSize=image.size else{
            return
        }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize,false,1.0)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else{
            return
        }
        context.setShouldAntialias(true)
        context.setAllowsAntialiasing(true)
        context.setShouldSubpixelQuantizeFonts(true)
        context.interpolationQuality = .high
        imgCanvas.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: (imgCanvas.image?.size.width)!, height: (imgCanvas.image?.size.height)!))
        bezeirPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezeirPath.move(to: fromPoint)
        bezeirPath.addLine(to: toPoint)
        bezeirPath.lineWidth=(CGFloat(widthOfLine) * scaleX )/scrollView.zoomScale
        bezeirPath.lineCapStyle = CGLineCap.round
        bezeirPath.lineJoinStyle=CGLineJoin.round
        bezeirPath.flatness=0.0
        bezeirPath.miterLimit=0.0
        bezeirPath.usesEvenOddFillRule=true
        UIColor.white.setStroke()
        bezeirPath.stroke(with: .clear, alpha:0)
        bezeirPath.close()
        bezeirPath.fill()
        UIColor.clear.set()
        context.addPath(bezeirPath.cgPath)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

opencv code:

```
Mat source;
    UIImageToMat(originalImage,source,true);

    return MatToUIImage(source);
```

I tried various ways to solve this issue, looking at different sources, but none worked. I have been trying to solve this for the past 3 days. So please if anybody has even any clue related to this issue, that would be helpful!
[[image: in picture you can see black pixels near transparent edge that is unwanted pixels that black pixels is produce by opencv [1]]

Comment: Can you please show what it is doing, and how you want it to look?

Comment: there is black pixels in edge of transparent pixels  that need to be transparent

Comment: What are you doing with the image in OpenCV? Can you show an example of the final image you are trying to create?

Comment: i have make pixels transparent in swift by setting antialasing true and send that image to opencv  for further process but just now i have convert image to  mat and return mat to uiimage and display  then above image result is shown code of opencv is above .... in case of antialiasing false that  problem is not occur but to smooth  sharp pixel i need to do antialiasing true...

Comment: I understand that. But once you have the image in OpenCV, what are you doing with it? What is the final product?

Comment: there is another algorithm to process image ,without using that algorithm just return  mat to uimage there is this problem

Comment: Does the image have to have alpha (eg transparency)? Is it going to be composited with another image in OpenCV?

Comment: image need to have transparent   , no composted with another image

Answer (score 0):

I would supply the RGB image and the A mask as separate images to OpenCV. Draw your mask into a single channel image:

```
guard let imageSize=image.size else{
        return
    }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize,false,1.0)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else{
        return
    }
    context.setShouldAntialias(true)
    context.setAllowsAntialiasing(true)
    context.setShouldSubpixelQuantizeFonts(true)
    context.interpolationQuality = .high
    context.setFillColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
    context.addRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height))
    context.drawPath(using: .fill)
    bezeirPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezeirPath.move(to: fromPoint)
    bezeirPath.addLine(to: toPoint)
    bezeirPath.lineWidth=(CGFloat(widthOfLine) * scaleX )/scrollView.zoomScale
    bezeirPath.lineCapStyle = CGLineCap.round
    bezeirPath.lineJoinStyle=CGLineJoin.round
    bezeirPath.flatness=0.0
    bezeirPath.miterLimit=0.0
    bezeirPath.usesEvenOddFillRule=true
    UIColor.white.setStroke()
    bezeirPath.stroke()
    bezeirPath.close()
    bezeirPath.fill()
    let maskImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Then in OpenCV, you can apply the A image to your RGB image.

```
Mat source, sourceMask
UIImageToMat(image, source, true)
UIImageToMat(maskImage, sourceMask, true)
```

If your image isn't RGB, you can convert it:

```
cvtColor(source, source, CV_RGBA2RGB)
```

If your mask isn't single channel, you can convert it:

```
cvtColor(sourceMask, sourceMask, CV_RGBA2GRAY)
```

Then split the RGB image into channels:

```
Mat rgb[3];
split(source, rgb);
```

Then create RGBA image with the RGB channels and alpha channel:

```
Mat imgBGRA;

vector<Mat> channels = {rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], sourceMask};
merge(channels, imgBGRA);
```

Since your mask was created with anti-aliasing, the image created above will also have anti-aliased alpha.

Comment: No, but there is no reason why it shouldn't work. I pretty much wrote it all for you - not much is needed for you to test it.

Comment: you are using function of  cv.function like python  and python doesn't have semicolon ended

Comment: I didn't know if you were using objective-c or not for the OpenCV code. Wasn't sure how your name space is configured. Shouldn't be hard to figure it out, but I will remove that.

Comment: i had already split  channels  of source and added to gray scale image but that doesn't solved problem

Comment: It shouldn't. The way I propose is not changing the RGB content at all. Black/white is only drawn to the Alpha channel - so its pretty much impossible for it to change the RGB pixels to black.

Comment: what is source here?

Comment: `source` is converted from `image` which is your unmasked color image that you want to mask.

Comment: i have only one image input which i contains transparent pixels   produce by swift  and i have send that to opencv  here your code seems two input image UIImageToMat()

Comment: You show a RGB image masked by your bezierpath. I adapted your code to draw just a mask without your input image - called `maskImage`. So use that for the mask and use the image you were inputting into that code as the source image, called `image`.

Comment: When creating the mask image, fill with black and draw the bezier path white (or vice versa depending on what you want masked), but it doesn't use your input image.

Comment: there can be many white or  pixels which need not  to be touch so that this method cannot works

Comment: You would be doing the same thing, but just applying the mask in OpenCV instead of with your Swift code. Instead of creating a masked image with your swift code, you are creating only a mask. Then you apply that mask to your image in OpenCV,

Comment: i am not creating any mask for opencv  using swift

Comment: You show a masked image, correct? My solution just proposes you create the mask separately, then apply it to your image in OpenCV.

Comment: masked image which you assume is passed  to opencv and in opencv covert that image  to mat and for now nothing done then  mat is convert to uiimage and display that  as shown image above in picture

Comment: Guess we are having a communication problem. I give up. I'm sure my suggestion would work if you tried it. Good luck.

Comment: Actually though, I should have said that `image` is `imgCanvas.image`.

Comment: if image is imgCanvas.image  then it makes whole result image transparent

Answer (score -1):

OpenCV can help you find edges using Canny Edge Detector You can refer for the implementation in this link

OpenCV's Canny Edge Detection in C++

Furthermore, I would like you to first do a bit of research on your own before actually asking for questions here.